# ARFIMA covariance structure

Tags: arima, covariance, brownian-motion, long-range-dependence, arfima

I have a set of response processes (queue lengths in infinite server network).

Using queue theory, I can numerically calculate response autocovariance structure, from the known service time distribution.

Example: Exponential service time distribution yields AR(1) covariance structure in the response. However we model service times by the gamma distribution, often with long tail.

Our objective is interpretation of a fitted gamma distribution, as to its impact on response dynamics. And we are particularly interested in long range dependence in the response dynamics.

We had the idea to relate the calculated covariance structure to ARFIMA(0,d,0) so as to find a Hurst exponent that summarizes conveniently the long range dependence implied by that service time distribution.

For small lags the Arfima model is of course no good. We thought to compare true and model power spectra, to evaluate the importance of this misfit.

Do you think the above is correct and practical, to achieve our goal which I hope is clear from above.

Second question then: How to go about fitting Arfima (p,d,q) to an **autocovariance function**? Rather than to a time series e.g. arfima(x, order=..., lmodel=...).

Comment: Trying to understand your actual question; are you asking whether ARFIMA is suitable for predicting queue dynamics from residence time distribution?

Comment: Are you asking for a software implementation of ARFIMA model? There is more than one option in R (e.g. in package "rugarch"), and probably in other statistical packages.

Comment: @Richard Hardy Question edited. Yes I try to use Arfima(0,d,0) to characterize long range dependence in response process, as implied by a particular gamma service time distribution. Model must only fit well for large lags, that's our main interest.

Comment: For the second question, you mean how to find an ARFIMA model that yields a particular autocovariance function? What's wrong with fitting ARFIMA to the data and expecting that the underlying autocovariance will be captured as well as possible? Perhaps it is a matter of objective function (or loss function): you care not about ARFIMA's fit to the data but aucovariance's due to ARFIMA fit to a given autocovariance. Did I get it right? In other words, you want to compare $\widehat{f(x)}$ to $f(x)$ rather than $\hat{x}$ to $x$, where $x$ is data, $f(.)$ is autocovariance, and hats ~ fitted values.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: Thank you for your time! I understand what you say, I should not forget standard modeling practice. But I have no data, only a sample ACF. I don't know any R-function that fits a model to a covariance function, they all take a time series and then calculate sample ACF! Our objective was to find a simple relation between gamma rate/shape and Hurst exponent aka long range dependence, but I guess we saw it too simple.

Comment: Well, it should be possible to do it your way, too; it will just take a little time to figure out how.

Comment: @Richard Hardy: You approve of our logic? :-)   Say we have a sample ACF that exhibits MA(1) features. Say we decide to fit an MA(1) model. Parameter estimate can simply be read from the first sample autocorrelation. We want to do the same but for an ARFIMA(0,d,0). And estimate d by equating true ACF decay to asymptotic h^(2d-1) power law decay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31073/discussion-between-user3817704-and-richard-hardy).